# How do I make the columns of a CSV as arrays with the header being the key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach

I have a csv file which I need to extract data from us use. I need to create an individual array from each column so:

[image: example table]

I need heading1 as the key and the values as data1, data2, data3.

I guess I need the key so I can access a particular column.

Comment: do a read csv & do a simple for loop to create the desired array using the array key as `header`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first row, then use `array_combine` as you iterate over the subsequent rows to use the values from the header row as array keys.

```
$file = fopen('yourfile.csv', 'r');

$keys = fgetcsv($file);   // get the headers

while (false !== ($values = fgetcsv($file))) {
    $row = array_combine($keys, $values);   // combine headers with values
    // now you can do
    $value = $row['heading1']; //etc.

}
```

Comment: ``false !== ..`` 10/10 clarity.